# get value of string array

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I've made a string array in my array.xml:

```
 <string-array name="question1">
 <item value="1">A</item>
 <item value="0">B</item>
 <item value="0">C</item>
 <item value="0">D</item>
```

Now I would like to get the value of that array into my java file. How can I access this value? Or isn't this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show any research or attempt at solving the issue priori to asking the question

Comment: I did do research. Tried finding the answer. All I could find wasn't relevant to my question. That's why I didn't add that. Don't judge to fast..

Comment: really? that's hard to imagine, as this topic is largely covered in the documentation ... see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. Because I still can't find the value of the item. I don't want the value 'A' I want the value '0' or '1'. Still can't find that in the documentation..

Comment: Look again at the documentation. There is no attribute `value` anywhere. What would make you think it exists?

Comment: Is it weird that I was looking at what I could read in the documentation, instead of what isn't in the docs?

Comment: i don't understand your question, but possibly an answer would be: the doc defines a string-array as containing a list of items, items that don't have any attribute whatsoever. I don't see what would make someone believe that there could be attributes anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say that StringArray does not define any item attributes. In your case "value" is an attribute.

Here's the reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: Thank you very much, will try to make a workaround!

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] questionArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.question1);
```

Access it like this. To get the value inside the array use `questionArray[index]`

[public String[] getStringArray (int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getStringArray%28int%29)

> Added in API level 1
>
> Return the string array associated with a particular resource ID.
>   Parameters id     The desired resource identifier, as generated by the
>   aapt tool. This integer encodes the package, type, and resource entry.
>   The value 0 is an invalid identifier. Returns
>
> ```
> The string array associated with the resource.
> ```
>
> Throws Resources.NotFoundException    Throws NotFoundException if the
>   given ID does not exist.

Comment: ya.. its 100% right..

Comment: I don't want to get the array itself. I would like to receive the value of the items.

Comment: The array will be having all the values inside it

Comment: I won't get the value like 0 or 1. As in `<item value="1">A</item>`

Comment: I don't think that would be possible.